# Limit does not preserve strict inequality

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

When I was reading Rudin's proof of L'Hospital's Rule, I was confused with the following two lines. Since my question is not directly related to the proof itself but more on the limiting behavior of functions, I will only mention the part I don't understand. The set up is that functions $f,g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, the limit of $\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}$ exists and quals to $A$, which could be anything on the extended real line.

1. Given that $$\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{g(x) - g(y)} =\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)} < r,$$ where we can treat $x$ as the variable, $y$ and $t$ as fixed, then as $x\to a$, Rudin wrote $$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}\le r. $$
2. Given that $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}< r - \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}+\frac{f(y)}{f(x)},$$ if we let $x\to a$, then $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < r .$$

Notice the first one changes to $\le$ after taking the limit while the second one remains $<$. May I ask if there is a general rule on this? Could it be related to limsup or liminf?

New update: I was actually misquoted the second part - Rudin wrote $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}< q$ directly.

Comment: You've misquoted the formula in item 2! It's $f/g < q$, not $f/g < r$. (And $r<q$ by definition, so it follows from $f/g \le r < q$.)

Comment: When I was reading the line $f/g < q$, I thought he skipped the line $f/g < r$ and $r< q$. Now I realized it is actually $f/g \le r < q$. That makes 1 and 2 align with each other. In sum, whenever we take the limit, we just replace the strict inequality with the normal ones ($\le, \ge$) to be on the safe side. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.